# How to get byobu to launch tmux instead of screen?

Tags: byobu, tmux

The latest versions of byobu should apparently be configurable to run tmux instead of screen, but I haven't been able to.
Advice appreciated

Comment: Isn't tmux an alternative to byobu+screen?

Comment: @Oli it is supposed to be an alternative, yes.

Answer (score 42):

Byobu 5.x has excellent support for tmux.  New installations of Byobu 5.x and above will default to using tmux as the backend.  Upgrades from older versions, however, will not automatically make that switch.

Still, you can manually run byobu with tmux by typing `byobu-tmux`.  Similarly, you can manually choose to run with the screen backend by typing `byobu-screen`.

Running `byobu` will launch with your selected default backend.  You can choose between `tmux` and `screen` by running `byobu-select-backend`.

```
kirkland@ubuntu:~$ byobu-select-backend 

Select the byobu backend:
  1. tmux
  2. screen

Choose 1-2 [1]: 1
```

Comment: I have tmux and screen on Ubuntu 11.10.  I totally uninstalled byobu, including deleting ~/.byobu directory, then installed byobu 5.10 from the launchpad-specified repository.  It not only defaults to screen, and when I run `byobu-select-backend`, it shows tmux as the default, and I select tmux, but when I run byobu, it uses screen.  Only if I run `byobu-tmux` will it use tmux.  I think maybe byobu just doesn't like me.

Comment: I had the same problem marty. I trashed by .byobu directory and re-installed and things worked though.

Comment: I followed the instructions as you said, but when I print the value of $TERM var, "screen" is returned... why ?

Answer (score 3):

I just installed the latest version of Byobu on Ubuntu 10.10 by following these instructions:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:byobu/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install byobu
```

From here: https://launchpad.net/byobu/

Then you can launch it with `byobu-tmux`