# Byobu doesn't show the colourful status line

Tags: byobu

I just followed this [How to get byobu to launch tmux instead of screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50655/how-to-get-byobu-to-launch-tmux-instead-of-screen)  and updated byobu on my Ubuntu 11.04 64bit notebook.

When I was using the old version from Ubuntu repos, there always was this colorful status line.  With the new version, I no longer see it. I selected tmux as the backend, but the result looks like a bare-bone screen.

Furthermore, <kbd>F9</kbd> shows only 4 options:

- Help
- Toggle status notifications
- Change escape sequence
- Byobu currently does not launch at login (toggle on)

BTW, here is what I have in my $HOME/.byobu:

```
zperry@nb1:~/.byobu$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry   19 2012-05-27 23:06 backend
lrwxrwxrwx 1 zperry zperry   33 2012-05-28 00:08 byobu ->   /home/zperry/.local/share/byobu
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry   38 2012-05-27 23:43 color
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry    0 2012-05-27 22:59 disable-autolaunch
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry   43 2012-05-27 23:43 keybindings
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry   58 2012-05-27 23:05 keybindings.tmux
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry   40 2012-05-27 23:43 profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry   43 2012-05-27 23:43 profile.tmux
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry    0 2012-05-27 23:39 reload-required
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry 1802 2012-05-28 00:08 status
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry    0 2012-05-27 23:22 status.disable
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry 1368 2012-05-27 23:43 statusrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 zperry zperry    0 2012-05-27 23:43 windows
```

Any hints as to how I can recover the colourful status line, and these missing options?

Comment: I became curious about this zero-sized file status.disable, so I mv-ed it to no.status.disable and got back the colourful status line. Nevertheless, I still don't see a way to recover these missing F9 options, such as setting background/foreground colors.

Comment: The byobu-quiet --undo did remove the status.disable file, but tmus chipped in and generated some warnings: tmux: unknown option -- X
usage: tmux [-28lquvV] [-c shell-command] [-f file] [-L socket-name]
            [-S socket-path] [command [flags]]

Answer (score 12):

In you case, you have explicitly disabled your status line, as you can tell by the flag file `status.disable`.  You can either remove this file or run `byobu-quiet --undo`.

It looks like you figured this out and answered your own question in the comment.  As to your new question in your comment, we have disabled a few of the infrequently used and hard to maintain menu options, which includes the background/foreground color setting.

To set the foreground/background colors, you have two options now:

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> to set it to a random 256-color combination
- Or manually edit `$HOME/.byobu/color.tmux`

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of Byobu.*

Comment: The byobu-quiet --undo did remove the status.disable file, but at the same time I got: tmux: unknown option -- X
usage: tmux [-28lquvV] [-c shell-command] [-f file] [-L socket-name]
            [-S socket-path] [command [flags]]

Comment: Furthermore, I noticed two new issues: with Ubuntu 11.04, neither byobu-tmux nor byobu-screen has the Ubuntu (distribution name) properly displayed on the status bar.  With 11.10, byobu-tmux doesn't show anything, almost like what you would get after running byobu-silent!

Comment: Forgot to mention: I first tested byobu's behaviour on Ubuntu 11.10 over a ssh connection.  When I went to the machine's console, after a few trials, I got the status bar with byobu-tmux.  But once I went back to ssh access, again everything disappeared.  byobu-screen however worked fine either direcly or over a ssh connection.  I would be happy to provide screen shots if there is a way to attach such pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and **the problem was solved by removing the screen hardstatus and caption (comment out those lines in ~/.screenrc).** Byobu will then put its own hardstatus in their place.

Answer (score 1):

If you resize the terminal real small and the status line info doesn't fit, the status line disappears. Resize the terminal larger again and the status comes back! It's a feature disguised as a bug ;-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/652495)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes it does, think about it. I had the same problem, landed here, the above solutions did not work for me because my terminal window was too small. The Q&A here is for everyone with the same problem, not only the author's exact circumstances.